# 8 A Letters in Boxes next to OS X Logo in Overview Panel

Tags: macos

When I opened Mac OS X overview panel to check out how much storage I have left, I saw this strange thing. It doesn't affect the performance by any means, but it is not aesthetically pleasing. How can I get rid of it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some sort of typeface issue, have you changed any system fonts around? If you have, restoring the fonts, then rebooting should fix the problem.

Open Font Book, go to File > Restore Standard Fonts. Read the warning carefully, then click Proceed.

Comment: For some reason, the text "Yosemite" was replaced by weird characters, but it came back when I restarted the computer.